# C# RushHour iterative deepenig, optimization

Tags: c#, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I have to solve the rushhour problem using iterative deepening search, I'm generating new node for every move, everything works fine, except that it takes too much time to compute everything and the reason for this is that I'm generating duplicated nodes. Any ideas how to check for duplicates?

First I start at the root, then there is a method which checks every car whether is it possible to move it if yes, new node is created from the current node but the one car that has valid move replaced with new car that has new coordinates.

Problem is that the deeper the algorithm is the more duplicates moves there are.

I have tried to not to replace the car, but used the same collection as was used in root node but then the cars were moving only in one direction.

I think that I need to tie car collection somehow, but don't know how.

[The code](http://pastebin.com/jiuVj87v)

Any ideas how to stop making duplicates?

Off topic: I'm new to C# (read several tutorial and then have been using for 2 days) so can you tell me what I'm doing wrong or what should I not do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with iterative deepening, then the simplest solution may be to build a hash table. Then all you need to do with each new node is something like

```
NewNode = GenerateNextNode
if not InHashTable(NewNode) then
  AddToHashTable(NewNode)
  Process(NewNode)
```

Alternately, the number of possible positions (nodes) in RushHour is fairly small (assuming you are using the standard board dimensions) and it is possible to generate all possible (and impossible!) boards fairly easily. Then rather than iterative deepening you can start with the 'solution' state and work backwards (ticking off all possible 'parent' states) until you reach the start state. By working on the table of possible states you never generate duplicates, and by tagging each state once it is visited you never re-visit states.

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried and why it didn't work? (Note that the alternate solution I suggested did work for me).

Comment: You can also search both forwards from the start state, and backwards from the end state, in parallel (think breadth-first-search, but actual concurrency might work as well).
You get a solution once the two searches meet in the middle, thus cutting the necessary search tree depth in half.